# Is a liaison after "SUR" a forbidden liaison or an optional liaison?

Tags: liaisons

I know that the mandatory liaisons for prepositions are the following:

Dans = In [dɑ̃]

En = In  [ɑ̃]

Sans = Without  [sɑ̃]

Chez = At (“z” sounds like “z”)  [ ʃe] VERIFIED

Sous = Under…  [su]

Dès = From [de̞]

But how about Sur = On?

As in "Sur un" is [syr œ̃] OR [sy‿rœ̃] ???

Comment: Salut, can you narrow this down to your question about  *sur* and show anything you've found where it's not /syr/ ? There are cases where liaison is not mandatory with other words in your list.    
 What is the difference between /syrœ̃/ and /syrœ̃/ for you? (‿ =/= IPA; there are no spaces or word breaks needed)

Comment: In French, unlike some languages, there are generally no verbal cues as to when one word ends and the next begins. So, ignoring context, *su rêver* is hard to tell apart from *sur Ève et*.

Comment: Look up [enchaînement](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/pronunciation/enchainement/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liaisons are about consonants normally "mute" when no other word follows but the *R* in *su**r*** is always pronounced so the question about whether a liaison should be made or not doesn't exist.

The liaison is not always mandatory after *chez*. It is mandatory in *che**z** eux* and *che**z** elle* but not in *chez Antoine* or *chez Élisabeth*. Similar rules with *sous*, *sans*, *dès*...